# Как заставить пример работать в safari?

Tags: вёрстка, css3, css-animation

Opera, chrome, ie, firefox - во всех браузерах работает, а в safari не хочет.

```
    button:hover {
    animation: btn-scale .5s ease;
}

@keyframes btn-scale {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qhkrxmh5/1/

Comment: может для этого использовать vendor prefixes = -webkit ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1mq7gxtp/ - пример

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/qhkrxmh5/4/

```css
button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

button:hover {
    -webkit-animation: btn-scale .5s ease 1;
    animation: btn-scale .5s ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes btn-scale {
      0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1);   }
     50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.3); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1);   }
}

@keyframes btn-scale {
      0% { transform: scale(1);   }
     50% { transform: scale(1.3); }
    100% { transform: scale(1);   }
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Сначала думал, что хватит `@-webkit-keyframes`, но оказалось, что нет.